# good name for abstract tower property of conditional expectation

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, category-theory

I'm trying to find a good phrase to describe the following simple property of a function $f \colon A \times B  \to A$, where $A$ is some set and $B$ is some partially ordered set: For all $a \in A$ and $x,y \in B$ it holds that $x \leq y$ implies $$f(f(a,x),y) = f(a,y)$$

Examples of functions satisfying this property (or the related property with the inequality reversed) are set union and intersection ($A=B$, ordered by inclusion), orthogonal projection onto some Hilbert subspace, taking conditional expectation etc.

For conditional expectation, the above property is known as the *tower property* and of course one could simply continue to use this description for the abstract property, but I suspect that there is a better description, maybe using vocabulary from algebra or category theory.

Just to be clear: I'm looking for a plain English phrase (formula and variable free).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: maybe think of it as $f_y\circ f_x = f_y\circ i$, where $i$ is the identity...

Comment: Conceptually, you are thus somewhat related to a coequalizer ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer ), even though you probably lack universality...maybe you call it a coequalizer cone?

Comment: From union/intersection interpretation, these are known as *absorption laws*; the name is also used in lattice theory and, albeit rarely, in category theory when presented using $src, tgt$ as is done by Freyd and Scedrov.

Comment: I agree, saying that $f_y$ (resp. $f(.,y)$) absorps $f_x$ (resp. $f(.,x)$) whenever $y\geq x$ makes sense. Since your order on B defines an order on the $f_x$, what about calling it simply "absorption of smaller elements"?

Answer (score 1):

So, what you have is just a functor from A to the category Idem of Idempotent functions. Objects in Idem are idempotent functions (satisfying $f_x\circ f_x=f_x$) and there is a morphism from $f_y$ to $f_x$ if $f_y\circ f_x=f_y$. Specifically, your functor maps $x\in B$ into $f(.,x)$, and the mapping of morphisms guarantees that $f(f(.,x),y)=f(.,y)$ whenever $y\geq x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and answer, what you write makes sense. However, apart from a new point of view, the problem is still unsolved (because my original question was not well-formulated):  I would like describe the concept in plain English without using any formulas. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I would then stick to the word "idempotency", since this is essentially the concept you are generalizing. Maybe "conditional bi-idempotence": bi-idempotence because $f_y\circ f_x=f_y$, and conditional because this only holds if $y\geq x$?